# Lissajous Curve

Tags: geometry, algebraic-curves, parametric

$$ \gamma(t)= (x(t),y(t))=(sin(2t),sin(3(t)) $$

Justify that we can reduce the domain of study to [0, $\pi/2$], by specifying the necessary symmetries to obtain the whole curve.

I'm not really too sure how to do this. I know the curve is reflective in x=0, y=0 and has a rotational symmetry of $\pi$ but I'm not really sure how to answer the question

Thanks